# How to run multiple .sql files in Eclipse DTP

Tags: sql, eclipse, stored-procedures

I've a list of .sql script files to create Stored Procedures which I'm using the Eclipse DTP to develop. Currently to create/update all these Stored Procedures, I've to open & run
one by one from the Data Perspective.

Is there a way to create a batch file that run the scripts along the lines of

```
    run createSP1.sql
    run createSP2.sql
    ...
    run createSPn.sql
```

and run it in the Eclipse DTP to avail of the DB connection defined there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just create a batch file that merges all of your `.sql` files together into a single `procs.sql` file as part of the build process. I don't know what platform you're running on but in Windows you could have a .bat file that does something like this:

```
type *.sql > proc.sql
```

then to apply it to the database, why not do it outside Eclipse and connect to the database via the command line. You could bundle this all up as a single batch file that gets the latest version of your stored procedures from source control, merges them into a single file and then applies it to the database.

Comment: @ninesided I kinda took your suggestion and ran with it. To keep it inside the Eclipse IDE I went looking at Ant so I now have an Ant script which, as you suggested, concatenates all of the .sql files in the directory into another file and then another task which runs this file against the DB. I am also now able to store tags in the SQL which get replaced with the correct environment variables for the target deployment platform. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

### Part I

As far as I know the developers of Eclipse DTP
have not yet implemented a command line SQL execution 
interface through the Eclipse console view.

See the following URL on the eclipse DTP developer forum
http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.dtp/msg00304.html

### Part II

While the Eclipse DTP people are working on it, 
you can use a database specific tool to load 
a master SQL file (all SQL proc files 
appended together)

There are database specific console 
tools that will load your master SQL file
command line.
(ie. SQL*Plus for Oracle, ij for Apache Derby)

### Part III

An improvement over DOS batch is using Cygwin bash
or python or perl to merge all of your sql files
together into a master file.

I found that the text processing tools available 
in UNIX (awk,sed,cat...) are great for this sort 
of thing.